# Have phenomenology influenced much of our contemporary science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, phenomenology

I'm reading the [phenomenology page](http://www.iep.utm.edu/phenomsc/) on IEP, which talks about the relation between phenomenology and science, and I must say, not that I haven't met with phenomenology before, but as it's presented on the page it seems that phenomenology is exactly the way science works nowadays, especially the idea of different aspects of the object, multiple experiments in multiple situations to have more comprehensive understanding of the object.

Is that true? Is our contemporary natural science works in the phenomenological method?

Comment: Phenomenology in the natural sciences usually means drawing out predictions from theory; for example you have string theory phenomenology.

Comment: @MoziburUllah see these quotes: "To grasp a scientific object, like a perceptual object, as a presence in the world, as “objective,” means, strangely enough, to grasp it as never totally given, but as having an unbounded number of profiles that are not simultaneously grasped. Such an object is embedded in a system of “referential implications” available to us to explore over time." "With sufficient apprehension of sampled profiles, “The unfamiliar object is … transformed …into a familiar object.”"

Comment: "But the object is never fully grasped in its complete presence, horizons remain, and the most one can hope for is for a thing to be given optimally in terms of the interests for which it is approached. And because theory and instruments are always changing, the same object will always be grasped with new profiles."

Comment: great quotes. Sometimes the familiar is transformed into something unfamiliar and new horizons open. Things 'doth suffer a sea-change into something rich and strange'.

Comment: @MoziburUllah so, my point being, at least as much as I've read in the page, the (kinda) inductive way of experimenting in different ways, different angles, different tests, seems to be drawn from phenomenology. Is that statement true? Or is it somehow the other way around, that Husserl draws the phenomenology lines of research from what was the experimental methods in his days?

Comment: Phenomenology in science refers to models that do not go into root causes and simply quantify/fit what is observed, e.g. statistical models are phenomenological. It has little to do with transcendental phenomenology as a philosophical movement founded by Husserl that the IEP article is about. The latter had some influence on human and social sciences, especially in Europe, but not much in natural sciences.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss: I'm not particularly acquainted with Hussels work but my impression is that Heideggers phenomenology was rooted in his understanding of poetry since poets take the world for granted and do philosophise abstractly and axiomatically in the manner of Descarte. They are already in the world.